# Функция структурирования категорий и подкатегорий PHP

Tags: php

Пишу функцию, которая должна структурировано строить список из категорий и подкатегорий, но не до конца получается как надо.

В базе есть по стандарту поля id, title, parent_id.
Если parent_id = 0, то это главная категория...

Мой код:

```
function ReintCategory($categories, $parent_id){

    $parent_isset = false;

    $result = '<ul class="sub_cat_menu">';
    foreach ($categories as $row) {

        // если id родительской категории = parent_id и у неё parent_id не 0
        if($parent_id == $row["parent"] && $row["parent"] != "0"){
            $parent_isset = true;
            $result .= '<li>'.$row["title"];

            ReintCategory($categories, $row["id"]);

            $result .= '</li>';
        }

    }
    $result .= '</ul>';

    if($parent_isset == true)
        echo $result;
}

echo '<ul class="editor_menu">';
foreach ($categories as $row) {

    if($row["parent"] == "0")
        echo '<li>'.$row["title"];

    ReintCategory($categories, $row["id"]);

    echo '</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Проблема именно в том, что рекурсивная функция не срабатывает на строке 68 (см. рисунок) и получается, что подкатегория, которая имеет ещё вложенные подкатегории - не срабатывает.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Видимо я что-то упустил.

Comment: возьмите mongodb и храните дерево там как оно есть. а вообще вам нехватает id левого и правого соседа

Comment: да и рекурсия как правила не очень хорошая идея. т.к. затруднен дебаг. плюс есть лимит на выполнение рекурсии по мойму 100 вызовов

Comment: @Naumov может все же количество вызовов  рекурсии зависит от количества памяти и сколько конкретная операция в этой памяти весит? не? .........`id левого и правого соседа` - нужно при другом способе хранения дерева... .. с толку не сбивайте людей

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ох да этот лимит в xdebug устанавливаеться

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто вы слегка не поняли логику работы своего же скрипта.

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
function ReintCategory($categories, $parent_id){

    $parent_isset = false;

    $result = '<ul class="sub_cat_menu">';
    foreach ($categories as $row) {

        // если id родительской категории = parent_id и у неё parent_id не 0
        if(($parent_id == $row["parent"]) && ($row["parent"] > 0)){
            $parent_isset = true;
            $result .= '<li>'.$row["id"].' '.$row["title"];

            $result .= ReintCategory($categories, $row["id"]);

            $result .= '</li>';
        }

    }
    $result .= '</ul>';

    if($parent_isset == true) {
        return $result;
    }
    return '';
}

$categories = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 2
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 1
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 6,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 7,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 6
    ],
    [
        'id' => 8,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 6
    ],
    [
        'id' => 9,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 5
    ],
    [
        'id' => 10,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 8
    ],
    [
        'id' => 11,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 10
    ],
    [
        'id' => 12,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 13,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 0
    ],
    [
        'id' => 14,
        'title' => 'HELLO',
        'parent' => 0
    ],
];

echo '<ul class="editor_menu">';
foreach ($categories as $row) {

    if($row["parent"] == 0) {
        echo '<li>'.$row["id"].' '.$row["title"];
        echo ReintCategory($categories, $row["id"]);
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Спасибо Станислав, всё заработало чётко. Скажите пожалуйста, чем этот вариант получения структурированного списка плох, судя по комментариям?

Answer (score 2):

Функция `ReintCategory()` должна принимать массив `$categories` по ссылке и удалять из него обработанные элементы, иначе все наследники будут выведены дважды. Ну, и как ответил @Stanislav, `ReintCategory()` должна не выводить, а возвращать результат:

```
function ReintCategory(&$categories, $parent_id){

    $parent_isset = false;

    $result = '<ul class="sub_cat_menu">';
    foreach ($categories as $key => $row) {

        // если id родительской категории = parent_id и у неё parent_id не 0
        if($parent_id == $row["parent"] && $row["parent"] > 0){
            $parent_isset = true;
            $result .= '<li>'.$row["title"];

            $result .=  ReintCategory($categories, $row["id"]);

            $result .= '</li>';
        }
        unset($categories[$key]);

    }
    $result .= '</ul>';

    if($parent_isset == true)
        return $result;
}

$categories = [
    ['parent' => 0, 'title' => 'Родитель', 'id' => 1],
    ['parent' => 1, 'title' => 'Дитё', 'id' => 2],
    ['parent' => 2, 'title' => 'Внук', 'id' => 3],
    ['parent' => 2, 'title' => 'Второй внук', 'id' => 4],
    ['parent' => 3, 'title' => 'Правнук', 'id' => 5],
    ['parent' => 3, 'title' => 'Второй правнук', 'id' => 6],
];

echo '<ul class="editor_menu">';
foreach ($categories as $row) {

    if($row["parent"] == "0")
        echo '<li>'.$row["title"];

    echo ReintCategory($categories, $row["id"]);

    echo '</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
```

**Результат:**

- Родитель

  - Дитё

    - Внук

      - Правнук
      - Второй правнук
    - Второй внук

**Результат без ссылки:**

- Родитель

  - Дитё

    - Внук

      - Правнук
      - Второй правнук
    - Второй внук
  - Внук

    - Правнук
    - Второй правнук
  - Второй внук
  - Правнук
  - Второй правнук

Comment: Спасибо postel объяснили чётко.

Answer (score 0):

Понимаю что не тянет на ответ но вот реализация на mongo
я не буду менять алгоритм который уже существует, но должен предупредить что в монго есть ограничения на размер документа по этому надо быть осторожнее

```
    // метод для подключения к mongodb находиться в абстрактном классе 
    // привожу его для понимания кода ниже
    /**
     * @return \MongoDB\Driver\Manager
     * */
    static function getConnect() {
        if(!is_null(self::$_connect)) {
            return self::$_connect;
        }
        self::$_connect = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager(Config_Db::getConf()['mongodb']['connect']);
        return self::$_connect;
    }

    // наш контроллер

    /**
     * add comment action
     */
    public function addCommentAction()
    {
        $time = time();
        // массив с данными комментария
        //insert new comment to the page
        $arrData =  array(
            'page' => $_POST['page_id'], // id страницы в mongo
            'time' => $time, // время написания комментария
            'name' => $_POST['name'], // имя написавшего
            'comment' => $_POST['comment'] // сам комментрарий
        );

        $connect = Core_Model_Mongo::getConnect(); // подключение к монгодб

        // две строки ниже подготовка к записи так как они не относятся к алгоритму 
        // то в дальнейшем я не буду на них заострять внимание
        $write = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(); 
        $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY); 

        // и так, если человек отвечает на чей-то комментарий, то к нам приходит reply с id комментария
         if(isset($_POST['reply']) && !empty($_POST['reply'])) {
            // id комментария       
            $reply = $_POST['reply'];
            // путь для сохранения комментария
            // другими словами, это путь по которому будет сохранен комментарий
            $path = '';
            if(isset($_POST['path']) && !empty($_POST['path'])) {
                $path = $_POST['path'];
            } else {
                $path = 'replies';
            }

            // собственно, обновление данных по комментарию
            $write->update(
                array('_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($reply)), // загружаем комментарий 
                array('$push' => array($path => $arrData) ) // делаем push, в существующие данные, относительно path
            );

        } else {
            $write->insert($arrData); // если комментарий новый вставляем в базу
        }

        // запускаем запрос
        $connect->executeBulkWrite(Config_Db::getConf()['mongodb']['db'] . '.comments', $write, $writeConcern);

        // и возвращаемся обратно 
        header('Location:' . $_POST['back_url']);
    }
```

Это метод сохранения элемента в дерево, для примера я взял свой код, тут приведена следующая логика в каждой главной категории храняться под категории, в данном примере кода это "коментарии", но их легко можно заменить на категории что к стати генерация меню у меня происходит по другой логике там собственно есть только 'root' и его дочерние элементы пример кода можно посмотреть сдесь https://github.com/lnroma/ncms/blob/master/Modules/Pages/Controller/Index.php в частности метод `saveMenuAction()`

```
    /**
     * save menu
     */
    public function saveMenuAction() {
        try {
            $connection = Core_Model_Mongo::getConnect();
            $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(array('key' => $_POST['parent']));
            $existCursor = $connection->executeQuery(Config_Db::getConf()['mongodb']['db'].'.menu',$query);
            $existCursor = $existCursor->toArray();
            $existCursor = reset($existCursor);
            if(count($existCursor) > 0) {
                $data = array($_POST);
                $dataOld = $existCursor;
                if(isset($dataOld->child)) {
                    $data = array_merge($data,$dataOld->child);
                }
                Core_Model_Mongo::update( array(
                        '$set' => array(
                            'child' => $data
                        )
                    ),
                    'menu'
                    ,
                  array('key' => $_POST['parent'])
            );
            } else {
                Core_Model_Mongo::insert($_POST,'menu');
            }
            Core_Model_Mongo::getConnect()->close();
            header('Location:'.$_POST['back_url']);
        } catch(Exception $err) {
            header('Location:'.$_POST['back_url']);
        }
    }
```

т.е. при выборке мы получим что то вроде array для упрощения в действительности будет объект который будет содержать массив дочерних элементов

```
   array (
       'name' => 'test',
       'comment' => 'test comment',
       'reply' => array (
              [0] => 
                   array( 
                       'name' => 'test reply test'
                       'comment' => 'test comment reply'
                       'reply' => array (
                                  [0] => 
                                        array( 
                                             'name' => 'test reply test'
                                             'comment' => 'test comment reply'
                                        )
                                   )
                             )
                        )
                  );
```

ну и покажу логику отображения меню

```
<div class="well">
    <ul class="nav nav-list">
        <?php foreach ($this->getMenu() as $key => $value): ?>
            <li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header"><a href="<?php echo Core_App::getBaseUrl().$value->key ?>"><?php echo $value->title ?></a></label>
                <ul class="nav nav-list tree col-lg-offset-2">
                    <?php if (isset($value->child)): ?>
                        <?php foreach ($value->child as $key => $_child): ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo Core_App::getBaseUrl().$_child->key ?>"><?php echo $_child->title ?></a></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

меню находиться в отдельном template, если опустить всё ненужное у нас получиться следующая логика:

```
foreach($menu as $_menu) {
    echo $_menu['properties']; // это псевдо свойство, и давайте считать что оно содержит имя ид и т.д.
    echo(isset($_menu['child'])) {
       foreach($_menu['child'] as $_child) {
          echo $_menu['properties'];
       }
    }
}
```

т.е. в моей системе обусловлено что меню может быть двух уровнем, в дальнейшем хочу переделать отображение на рекурсивный вызов второго `foreach`, для того что бы можно было,  в админке устанавливать глубину навигации, а с точки зрения программиста это количество рекурсивных вызов второго `foreach()` а это равно тому что функция рекурсии будет вызванна столько раз сколько она может быть вызвана.

Есть ещё вариант отображения без рекурсии но тогда надо переформировать массив(опятьже грубо говоря) добавив ему глубину и сортировку и представить данные в виде одномерного(псевда одномерного) массива, следющей предпологаемой структуры

```
id|level|value
1 | 1   | test
2 | 1   | test2
3 | 2   | test3
4 | 3   | test4
5 | 1   | test5
```

И тут очень хорошо прослеживаеться логика представления т.е. просто берём пробегаемся `foreach` по массиву и относим элемены на столь, на сколько указан его level. К примеру у нас получиться что то подобное этому

```
-test
-test2
--test3
---test4
-test5
```

т.е. визуально мы видем сформированное дерево просто использовав level и всего один цикл.

Для того что бы реализовать схему с одномерным массивом на mysql понадобиться ещё два поля `left_id` и `right_id` и пока `sort` отпускаем, что нам необходимо для этого просто написать запрос который выберит все данные с таблицы и сгрупирует в один массив, с учётом правого соседа и левого, этот ход позволит встать элементу именно между теми элементами которые нужны. `level` не учавствует в выборке а sort нужен что бы сортировать дочерние элементы между родительскими.

Ну и на последок есть специальные граффовые базы данных для хранения  деревьев. https://habrahabr.ru/post/274383/
 P.S. Ошибка у вас скорее всего не в алгоритме а в данных.
 P.P.S. Смело минусуйте ответ только отписывайтесь почему? Я стараюсь учитывать конструктивные замечания, и даже если просто по какой либо личной не приязне минусуете тоже пишите.